# Python: Pass a value to drop down using mechanicalsoup and extract content

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to extract content from a dynamic webpage. My requirement is to select the seat style for this particular chair and then extract the values from the table of the web page. I used the following code. And the output is shown below:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
browse_page = browser.get('http://catalog.atsfurniture.com/9-grid-back-wood-chair.aspx')
browse_form = browse_page.soup.select("option",{"value":"Select Seat Style"})

browse_form.find(attrs={"option": "Select Seat Style"})['value'] = 'Solid Wood Seat'
#browse_form.find(attrs={"name": "password"})['value'] = 'password'

page2 = browser.submit(browse_form, browse_url)
print(str(page2.text))
```

Output:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4872094ff9a8> in <module>()
      3 browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
      4 browse_page = browser.get('http://catalog.atsfurniture.com/9-grid-back-wood-chair.aspx')
----> 5 browse_form = browse_page.soup.select("option",{"value":"Select Seat Style"})
      6 
      7 browse_form.find(attrs={"option": "Select Seat Style"})['value'] = 'Solid Wood Seat'

C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in select(self, selector, _candidate_generator, limit)
   1516                     print("    Running candidate generator on %s %s" % (
   1517                         tag.name, repr(tag.attrs)))
-> 1518                 for candidate in _use_candidate_generator(tag):
   1519                     if not isinstance(candidate, Tag):
   1520                         continue

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Irrelevant code is commented.

Is there any possible solution.

Thanks.